# Can someone explain consensus theorem for boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

In boolean algebra, below is the consensus theorem

$$X⋅Y + X'⋅Z + Y⋅Z = X⋅Y + X'⋅Z$$
$$(X+Y)⋅(X'+Z)⋅(Y+Z) = (X+Y)⋅(X'+Z)$$

I don't really understand it? Can I simplify it to

$$X'⋅Z + Y⋅Z = X' \cdot Z$$

I don't suppose so. Anyways, why can $Y \cdot Z$ be removed?

Comment: I think you should think about the distribution rule of boolean algebra. It is the counterpart of distribution rule of set operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proof that grep has given is fine, as is the one in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem), but they don’t give much insight into why such a result should be true. To get some feel for that, look at the most familiar kind of Boolean algebra: the Boolean algebra of subsets of some given set $S$, with $\cap$ for $\cdot$, $\cup$ for $+$, and $'$ interpreted as the relative complement in $S$ (i.e., $X' = S \setminus X$). In this algebra the theorem says that $$(X\cap Y) \cup (X' \cap Z) \cup (Y \cap Z) = (X\cap Y) \cup (X' \cap Z),$$ which amounts to saying that $$Y \cap Z \subseteq (X\cap Y) \cup (X' \cap Z).$$ This isn’t hard to prove, but doing so won’t necessarily give you any better feel for what’s going on. For that I suggest looking at the corresponding [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram), with circles representing $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. Shade the region representing $(X\cap Y) \cup (X' \cap Z)$. Now look at the region representing $Y \cap Z$: it’s already shaded, because it’s a subset of $(X\cap Y) \cup (X' \cap Z)$. Throwing it in with $(X\cap Y) \cup (X' \cap Z)$ to make $(X\cap Y) \cup (X' \cap Z) \cup (Y \cap Z)$ adds nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following:

$X \cdot Y + X' \cdot Z + Y \cdot Z $ =
$X \cdot Y + X' \cdot Z + (X + X') \cdot Y \cdot Z $ =
$X \cdot Y + X \cdot Y \cdot Z + X' \cdot Z + X' \cdot Y \cdot Z$ =
$X \cdot (Y + Y \cdot Z) + X' \cdot (Z + Y \cdot Z)$ =
$X \cdot Y + X' \cdot Z$

Answer (score 2):

Boolean Algebra has a very powerful [metatheorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra) that says that if any 2-element "{0, 1}" Boolean Algebra has a theorem, then it holds for all Boolean Algebras.  So, if you just want an argument that should come as convincing, you just need to check that all substitution instances of "0" and "1" in those equations.  Here's a compact argument:

Suppose x=0.  Then for the first equation we have 0.y+0'.z+y.z=0+1.z+y.z=z+y.z on the left-hand side, and 0.y+0'.z=0+1.z=z.  Well, z+y.z=z by absorption and commutation.  Now suppose x=1.  Then on the left hand side we have 1.y+1'.z+y.z=y+0.z+y.z=y+y.z.  On the right-hand side we have 1.y+1'.z=y+0.z=y.  So, the two sides equal each other by absorption.  So, the first equation holds.  In other words, it qualifies as a theorem.  The second equation follows by the De Morgan duality [metatheorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Duality_principle).  So, by the metatheorem which says that if any 2-element Boolean Algebra has a theorem, the consensus theorem holds for all Boolean Algebras.  If anything doesn't come as clear here, please don't hesitate to ask.

Why is this true?  Well, one could argue that Boolean Algebra originally got skillfully set-up as an algebraic system to behave like classical propositional logic, and in classical propositional logic where "=" gets taken as logical equivalence, each equality in your question corresponds to a theorem.  However, I suspect such an answer many people would find that explanation contentious at best.  Sometimes things in mathematics just hold true, because they do hold true... or many different explanations can get put forth to explain why something holds true.

Your can't simplify it to x'.z+y.z=x'.z  That is not an theorem in Boolean Algebra.  Suppose x=1, y=0, z=1.  Then, we have 0'.1+0.1=1.1+0=1 for the expression on the left-hand side, and 1'.1=0.1=0 on the right hand side.

Comment: You should be careful here when you state that if a theorem holds for the {0,1} Boolean algebra, then it holds for all Boolean algebras.  This is only true for theorems stated in the form of an identity.  (For all a,b,c,... some combinations of Boolean operators of a,b,c,... are equal.)  Obviously the theorem "the Boolean algebra contains exactly 2 elements" holds in {0,1} but not in an arbitrary Boolean algebra :)

Comment: @Ted You might have a point, but unfortunately your example didn't work here.  This "the Boolean algebra contains exactly 2 elements" does not hold in a 2-element Boolean algebra.  It consists of a true metaproposition (which you may call a metatheorem) *about* the 2-element Boolean Algebra.  The distinction here may take a while to appreciate.

Comment: No, it's not a metatheorem.  It's a first-order theorem in the language of the Boolean algebra, just like identities are.  "The boolean algebra contains exactly 2 elements" can be re-stated as: "There exists x,y in B such that x != y, and for all x,y,z in B, either x=y or y=z or x=z."  Identities are stated in the same way: "For all x,y in B, x+xy=x."  These are both statements in the object language,  not the metalanguage.  To distinguish these two cases, you need to restrict the form of the statement.

Comment: @Ted I don't see how one needs to restrict the form to distinguish those two cases.  The object language of Boolean Algebra consists of the axioms, and those statements that follow from the axioms.  I simply do not see how anything about the 2-element Boolean Algebra follows from the axioms, so unless you have a proof here, statements about the 2-element Boolean Algebra end up in the metatheory of Boolean Algebra.

Comment: Can you give a precise statement of your claim "If every 2-element Boolean algebra has a theorem, then it holds for all Boolean algebras" ?  Usually, I would interpret this statement to mean: "If a statement in the first order language of Boolean algebras holds in the Boolean algebra {0,1}, then it holds for all Boolean algebras."  Since the sentence "the boolean algebra consists of 2 elements" can be expressed in this language, your claim is false unless you restrict the kinds of statements you are considering.

Comment: @Ted Just because a statement can get written in a first-order symbolism, that doesn't mean you can express that statement in all particular first-order theories.  The law of commutation can get written in a first-order symbolism.  However, that does not mean that it can get expressed in the *pure* theory of groups.  The statement "if every 2-element Boolean Algebra has a theorem, then it holds for all Boolean Algebras" means that "if a statement holds in the first-order theory of 2-element Boolean Algebras, then it holds for all Boolean Algebras."

Comment: But the first-order statement "There exists x,y in B such that x != y, and for all x,y,z in B, either x=y or y=z or x=z" *does* hold in the first-order theory of 2-element Boolean algebras, because it is a first-order statement in the language of Boolean algebras which is true in all 2-element Boolean algebras.  And it does not hold in all Boolean algebras.

Comment: @Ted If so, then you could derive it from a sufficient axiom set for a Boolean Algebra.

Comment: You cannot derive it from the axioms of Boolean algebras because it is not true in *all* Boolean algebras, but nevertheless it is true for all *2-element* Boolean algebras.  So there are statements true for 2-element Boolean algebras that are not true for all Boolean algebras.

Comment: @Ted So, it's not in the object language of Boolean Algebras, since anything there can get derived from the axioms.  Since it's not in the object language of Boolean Algebras, it qualifies as a metaproposition about all 2-element Boolean Algebras.

Comment: The term "object language" usually refers to the set of all sentences in the language (first-order wffs of the language with no free variables).  It only depends on the symbols and their types (relations, functions,... ) and has nothing to do with any axiom system.  Besides, if we use your definition, then your claim reduces to "If a statement is derivable from the axioms of Boolean algebras, then it is true for all Boolean algebras."  The claim is trivial an
d has nothing to do with 2-element Boolean algebras anymore.

Comment: @Ted "Object language" doesn't just refer to the set of all sentences in the language.  A formal proof, with at least two wffs, consists of a *sequence* of wffs, which simply does not belong to the set of sentences in the language.  Formal proofs do belong to the object language (though their proof analysis does not).

Answer (score 1):

If Y and Z are both true, making the third term (YZ) true, and if X is also true, then the first term (XY) is also true making the third term redundant; if X is false, then the second term (X'Z) is also true, making the third term redundant. Since X must be either true or false, if the third term (YZ) is true, either the first or the second term must also be true, so the third term is always redundant.

Comment: This is a very old question and has a well-accepted answer. You have not contributed anything new. Please refrain from opening up old questions unless you have something new to contribute