# Boolean algebra consensus theory

Tags: boolean-algebra

I want to simplify $wxy + x'z + y'z + wz = wxy + x'z + y'z$ but I can't seem to use the consensus theorem at the right place.

I tried factoring cases for $x$ and $x'$ and $y$ and $y'$ but I don't know where to go. Can anyone give me just a hint (not the full answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

$$wxy+x'z+y'z+wz=wxy+(x'+y')z+wz=(xy)w+(xy)'z+wz$$

using distributive and De Morgan laws, and then apply the consensus theorem as stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60713/can-someone-explain-consensus-theorem-for-boolean-algebra?rq=1) with $X=xy$, $Y=w$, and $Z=z$.