# How to eliminate redundant logic term using simplification rules and expressions.

Tags: combinatorics, logic

This expression is right according to Karnaugh Map
[image]

Is it possible to eliminate extra term using Boolean algebra transformation and simplification rules? In other words - what is calculation process of this expression, which eliminates extra term.

Map:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "by combinatorics"? The Karnaugh map itself may be considered as a concept based on combinatorics.

Comment: I mean using Boolean Algebra simplification rules

Comment: Look up the consensus theorem.

Comment: @Fabio, yes, that is the answer - thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60724/599981